# How do I implement some sort of crypto material provider for the KeyChain in Android?

Tags: android, cryptography, keychain, smartcard

In Spain, every citizen has a national identity card (DNI), which is a NFC enabled smartcard that contains two client certificates and a public/private RSA key pair, stored securely on the card. All crypto operations are done securely on the smartcard.

I've successfully implemented in my Android app all it can offers, like access to public web services, document signing, etc. But everything is in-app.

I'd like to create some sort of generic middleware that provides crypto material to the KeyChain or something similar, so that when an app requests key material, for example Chrome when doing client certificate authentication, my app could be chosen, show up and set everything up.

Comment: I would like to do the same, with a different external source of keys.  Did you ever find a way to do this?  iOS/MacOS has TKToken app extension which does exactly that.

Comment: Nope, sorry. No way to add an external provider.

Comment: Bummer.  I wonder if only to make client certificates available to www browser?  Do they have there own extension points?  Other apps could build in SDK.